# create long list of variables based on existing variables

Tags: r

I have a long list of variables and for each I want to create a dummy variable. I am using the below dplyr mutate code to do this, but know that something like an array in SAS could be used (so I don't have to copy this line out multiple times). I just haven't been able to find an answer on Stack or anywhere else that fits.

```
Grade_Dist2 <- Grade_Dist2 %>% mutate(
   ACCT2301_FA15_z = ifelse(ACCT2301_FA15 %in% c("A", "B", "C"), 1, 
       ifelse(ACCT2301_FA15 %in% c("D", "F", "W", "Q"), 0, NA)))
```

The columns/vars are arranged together--all vars in the table are similar except an ID var.

Answer (score 1):

In the tidyverse you should probably look at something like `mutate_all()`, but in the meantime I would think something like this base R solution would work:

```
all_names <- grep("FA[0-9]+",names(Grade2),value=TRUE)
for (id in all_names) {
    cur_var <- Grade2[[id]]
    Grade2[[paste0(id,"_z")]] <- 
      ifelse(cur_var %in% c("A", "B", "C"), 1, 
         ifelse(cur_var %in% c("D", "F", "W", "Q"), 0, NA)))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a try at using a `tidyverse` approach with `mutate_all` as suggested by @BenBolker.

```r
library(tidyverse)
Grade_Dist2 <- tibble(ACCT2301_FA15_z = c("A", "F", "C", "Z"))

Grade_Dist2 <- Grade_Dist2 %>% 
  mutate_all(., funs(if_else(. %in% c("A", "B", "C"), 1, 
                             if_else(. %in% c("D", "F", "W", "Q"), 0, NA_real_))))

Grade_Dist2
#> # A tibble: 4 x 1
#>   ACCT2301_FA15_z
#>             <dbl>
#> 1               1
#> 2               0
#> 3               1
#> 4              NA
```

If you want to append the dummy variables to the existing data instead of overwriting then

```r
  mutate_all(., funs("dummy" = if_else(. %in% c("A", "B", "C"), 1, 
                                       if_else(. %in% c("D", "F", "W", "Q"), 0, NA_real_))))
```

will append variables with names like `ACCT2301_FA15_z_dummy` (or be called `dummy` if there is only one variable being mutated).

Comment: the only place where this solution falls short (I think) is that it overwrites the variables rather than assigning them a new name. Arguable whether that's good workflow design, but that's what the OP specified. (Still, +1)

Comment: @BenBolker, good point. Personally, I'd prefer to keep the original values too just to be sure the recode has worked as expected.  Adding a name to the `if_else` function inside the `funs` argument does this for us. See edited answer